# "of any sorts" vs "of any sort"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Given this sentence:

> I started using it to document the system (**we didn’t have documentations of any sorts**) and create our regression tests.

Concerning the part marked in bold, which would be the correct way to write it, *of any sort* or *of any sorts*?

Also, would either one of them be used in another case?

Comment: I'd recommend you to stick with *of any sort*.

Comment: 'Any sort' is probably better most of the time, but there are edge cases where maybe you could use 'sorts', which I don't feel sufficiently qualified to list. Related questions on English stack exchange: [The use of any with plural/singular words](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/116742/70061), [“Any” followed by singular or plural countable nouns?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/112996/70061)

Comment: *Of any sorts of [a name of a plant]* is quite common, but that's not what you are looking for. Examples of usage similar to yours: [1](https://books.google.rs/books?id=1nR85T1q0OQC&pg=PA263&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YndmVarlBcKe7gbGlYP4Dg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false), [2](https://books.google.rs/books?id=4JRkiLKnlkYC&pg=PA169&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5ndmVf_gN4ijU7qQgOAJ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false). The rules behind this? I have no idea, but I hope we'll find out if pazzo's generous offer produces the desired effect

Comment: @Lucky +1 for the second example (*of any sorts*). I could not read the first link due to viewing limitations on Google books, or something.

Comment: @pazzo the first one is from: *A Tale of Two Brothers: Jim Morrison & Michael Hutchence* by Jacqueline Murray - "Absolutely no heroin would have been found in my body, or cocaine, or anything but my prescription drugs from the doctor, alcohol and nicotine. There was never any reason for a cover-up **of any sorts**, but you see, Pamela didn't know how I died. She wasn't there." published by AuthorHouse, 2008.

Comment: @Lucky If you are interested you could write an answer with those two example uses quoted. That would be in answer in contention for the bounty, since no one else has provided examples. ;)

Comment: @pazzo will do :-) but I'm still hoping that someone more competent will do their "syntactic-semantic" magic and give an explanation about the construction. I'd really like to know more about the formal grammaticality of it...

Comment: @Lucky AuthorHouse is a vanity press. Any garbage can be "published" by them, as all a person has to do is pay them. You shouldn't use anything that they publish as an example of standard, edited, prose. They are not a commercial publishing house.

Comment: Who said we wanted standard edited prose, @F.E. Maybe we want standard unedited authorial prose, esp given the bounty mentions dialectal usage.

Comment: @ F.E. I suspected as much, that's why I looked for at least one more (I was guessing that University of Minnesota Press is OK, being a university). I'll look for more, but I'm more interested in the rules (if there are any) e.g can any be followed by plural (dictionaries say any of plural is OK but what about of any plural?). I just feel that digging up a few examples doesn't answer the question fully, but I thought they do indicate that the phrase might be idiomatic (somewhere).

Comment: @Lucky Yes, stuff that is vanity publish has the same quality as stuff that people put on their blogs: usually full of typos and not professionally edited--though, sometimes a few blogs are well written. If you're interested in searching for examples of common informal usage, then searching in novels that are published by commercial presses might be fruitful. -- Aside: there are some uses of "any plural-NP", e.g. *"There aren't any letters for you"*. But it might be that the OP's question is more related to the specific "NP of any sorts" type of construction. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been proven by other answers and comments that in this case *of any sort* is more common, safer and preferable to *of any sort**s***. The question remains - is *of any sorts* used at all? A Google books search of the phrase promptly returns 27100 results, but we shouldn't hold our breath yet. Many of those have to be discarded:

1. False positives: **of any sorts of** which is actually (of) **any sorts of** and this is not what the OP is asking about (but in case someone is wondering there are examples of: *any + plural + of* listed in [dictionaries](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/any_1));
2. False positives: Botany/gardening texts, where sort or sorts usually refers to a [plant variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_variety), which is not what the OP is asking about;
3. False positives: there was [one example](https://books.google.rs/books?id=qEg2AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA311&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bkJuVcHFDomwUeHogvAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) that contained a digitization error and *sorts* was actually *forts* in the original text;
4. Sources like [books from self published authors](https://books.google.rs/books?id=sk5nn9C4HLkC&pg=PT9&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8xtuVfvQDubTygPD_oKwBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false), [vanity publishers](http://www.sfwa.org/other-resources/for-authors/writer-beware/vanity/) (e.g. [1](https://books.google.rs/books?id=UfoUhpzAnXkC&pg=PT6&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gR1uVeX3E4LCywPB8oOAAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false), [2](https://books.google.rs/books?id=vZoNrKlnCp8C&pg=PA15&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=czVuVcXSFoLeU93BgYgM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) and probably [3](https://books.google.rs/books?id=IiRiRDQXtPoC&pg=PA261&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gR1uVeX3E4LCywPB8oOAAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) and [4](https://books.google.rs/books?id=pYPnNN8oUHIC&pg=PR13&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8xtuVfvQDubTygPD_oKwBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false)), speeches and [published letters](https://books.google.rs/books?id=dp1CAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA27&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8xtuVfvQDubTygPD_oKwBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) because it is likely that they were subjected to dubious editing or none at all.

Are there any examples left? Yes, there are.

- Publications by various universities (I certainly hope these contain proper grammar):

1.[The Business of Lobbying in China](https://books.google.rs/books?id=W2hwY3aCzMoC&pg=PA81&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SSduVZ-sIuW7ygP3r4OYCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) by Scott KENNEDY, Harvard University Press, 2005:

> *Large SOEs, such as Baogang, who could still profitably sell steel below the industry's average production costs (the standard by which price floors would be set) opposed **intervention of any sorts.***

2. [Philosophy and Its History: Issues in Philosophical Historiography](https://books.google.rs/books?id=JyB9mIB6B_AC&pg=PR15&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SSduVZ-sIuW7ygP3r4OYCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) by Jorge J. E. Gracia, SUNY Press, 1992:

> *This tendency to reject **absolutes of any sorts** is evident both in Anglo-American and Continental philosophy.*

3. [Philosophical Issues in Psychiatry: Explanation, Phenomenology, and Nosology](https://books.google.rs/books?id=XxEcxO7aSPMC&pg=PA214&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BjtuVeOZFcW1UdLAgPAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) by Kenneth S. Kendler, Josef Parnas, JHU Press, 2008:

> *Our best control panel for the disorders in which we are interested may turn out to involve combinations of **variables of any sorts.***

4. [The Yale Critics: Deconstruction in America](https://books.google.rs/books?id=4JRkiLKnlkYC&pg=PA169&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BjtuVeOZFcW1UdLAgPAM&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) edited by Jonathan Arac, Wlad Godzich, Wallace Martin, U of Minnesota Press, 1983:

> *Suffice it to say that this "engenderment" of the whole series by its exceeding supplement is neither that of an **emanation or creation of any sorts,** nor a constitution by means of a transcendental instance.*

- Something not published by universities?

  It seems to me that these two examples are published by houses whose editing and publishing procedures can be trusted (but I know next to nothing about publishing and publishers, so I cannot be absolutely sure):

1) [Paper Talk: A History of Libraries, Print Culture, and Aboriginal Peoples in Canada Before 1960](https://books.google.rs/books?id=7MnFLVRdOk4C&pg=PA111&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XT9uVY29E8LzUriLgbAO&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) by Brendan Frederick R. Edwards, [Scarecrow Press](https://rowman.com/Page/About), 2005

> *They have individual desks and libraries."103 No further announcements regarding **libraries of any sorts** would appear in the annual reports again until the 1950s.*

2) [Wittgenstein's (Misunderstood) Religious Thought](https://books.google.rs/books?id=am_TjzvRuR0C&pg=PA45&dq=%22of+any+sorts%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XT9uVY29E8LzUriLgbAO&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22of%20any%20sorts%22&f=false) by Earl Stanley B. Fronda, [BRILL](http://www.brill.com/), 2010

> *Be-ing is Nothing—beyond **ontology of any sorts** (“above and beyond speech, mind or being itself”)*

(emphasis mine in all examples)

Answer (score 5):

The phrase *of any sorts* returns **0** results in the British National Corpus, *of any sort* returns 150.
The difference in Google hits is massive.

In conclusion, *of any sort* is much more common than *of any sorts*, but both are used in English. Unfortunately I cannot find any specific documentation on this subject, so if you want to make sure you're using a correct form you should go for *of any sort*. It is unsure if *of any sorts* is correct.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: [Google ngram for *of any sorts* and *of any sort*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+any+sorts%2Cof+any+sort&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20any%20sorts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20any%20sort%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of *of any sort* being used. However, I believe the phrase *of any sorts* is grammatically incorrect. Considering that *any* is a singular quantifier, it would be improper to use it with a plural word like *sorts* or *kinds*.

However, I believe it is correct to use the phrase *of sorts* in conjunction with the singular form of the primary object.

Using your example,

> I started using it to document the system **(we didn’t have
>   documentations of any sorts)** and create our regression tests.

I find this statement to have an error in the part marked in bold. I am therefore rewriting it using the proper format below.

> I started using it to document the system **(we didn't have 
>   documentations of any sort)** and create our regression tests.

Another accurate way to say this would be:

> I started using it to document the system **(we didn't have ANY
>   documentation of sorts)** and create our regression tests.

Comment: The phrase *of sorts* is rarely used in negative sentences. It kinda has a different meaning.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, I edited to take out the `format`. It is not the custom to use that format on this site, and it bothers a lot of people, and it is hard ro read for others. Please do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

> I started using it to document the system (**we didn’t have documentations of any sorts**) and create our regression tests.

In this case, you should definitely use **of any sort**, which is correct (you could also use **of any kind**, or possibly **of any type**). You are effectively saying "We did not have documentation of even a single kind".

Although "sort" is sometimes found in the plural, it is in rather exceptional sorts of circumstance (like this one, where there are multiple types of circumstances). To say you had **documentation of sorts** is an idiomatic use of **of sorts**, meaning you had something that is barely documentation; this usage cannot be made negative, and doesn't work with "kinds" or "types".

You could probably get away with it with a definite article and relative clause:

> We could not find clothes of any of the sorts sold elsewhere

Note also that in British and American English, **documentation** is an uncountable noun and should be left singular. I know some uncountable nouns in English become countable, e.g. Indian English "baggages", but I've not heard of it with documentation.

Therefore, you should write:

> I started using it to document the system (**we didn’t have documentation of any sort**) and create our regression tests.

Answer (score 1):

[OALD's examples](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sort_1?q=sort) give us good information about it.

> "What ***sort of*** music do you like?" ~ "Oh, ***all sorts***!"

So, if we observe the example, it uses 'sort of' to talk about ***a*** particular type of music (say--rock). But then, the answer is **all types** (rock, classic, jazz, etc.).

If you read further...

> *This **sort of** problem is quite common./**These sorts of** problems are quite common.*

I think replacing 'sort' with 'type' helps us identify the word.

Said that,

> I started using it to document the system (we didn’t have documentations of any *<del>sorts</del> type*) and create our regression tests.

sounds better...

However, it's **possible** to use 'sorts' if you mean *many different* ones. OALD's example on the same page

> There are **all sorts of** activities (= ***many different ones***) for kids at the campsite.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the part marked in bold would be singular, but plural is apparently acceptable.

Taken from [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv310.shtml):

Kinds, sorts, types and even varieties can all be used interchangeably, (although varieties may be used more in more scientific sorts of contexts, e.g. varieties of tomato) The first three are very common and can be used in singular and plural forms.